# How to flatten an array with UNNEST or any other functions?

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose I get a temporary table with one field is an array, how to turn it to multiple rows ?

With PostgreSQL this can be done with UNNEST http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/21673/19

```
WITH x AS (SELECT ARRAY[1,3,2] AS arr)

SELECT UNNEST(arr) FROM x
```

Run the same query in BigQuery says *Syntax error: Unexpected
keyword UNNEST at [3:8]*

it seems in BigQuery the UNNEST can only be put after FROM clause,

Then I have tried these:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT ARRAY[1,3,2] AS arr)

SELECT * FROM UNNEST(x)
```

this one says *UNNEST cannot be applied on a table: x at [3:22]*; or this

```
WITH x AS (SELECT ARRAY[1,3,2] AS row)

SELECT * FROM UNNEST(x.arr)
```

says *UNNEST cannot be applied on a table: x.arr at [3:22]*

BTW, current temporary table x looks like this:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT ARRAY[1,2] AS row)

SELECT * FROM x
EOF

+--------------+
|     row      |
+--------------+
| [u'1', u'2'] |
+--------------+
```

while I am expecting to turn it into rows of value:

```
+-----+
| row |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
+-----+
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/arrays

Comment: anyone from Google can answer why not support a Postgres style standard `SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1,3,2])`

Answer (score 20):

Yet another version - with "explicit" UNNEST involved

```
WITH x AS (SELECT ARRAY[1,3,2] AS arr)
SELECT arr_item FROM x, UNNEST(arr) as arr_item
```

Comment: both answer here works as workaround; but anyone knows why not support a Postgres standard `SELECT UNNEST(...)` why not allow UNNEST function to be useable anywhere

Comment: but if no one from Google can answer here; I feel this `FROM x, UNNEST(arr) as arr_item` is more intuitive to understand

Answer (score 10):

You can do such flattening by doing CROSS JOIN of elements of arr with every row of x, i.e.

```
WITH x AS (SELECT ARRAY[1,3,2] AS arr)
SELECT arr FROM x, x.arr
```

or you can write it more explicitly as CROSS JOIN instead of using comma

```
WITH x AS (SELECT ARRAY[1,3,2] AS arr)
SELECT arr FROM x CROSS JOIN x.arr
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna create ordinary table by array, you can use UNNEST in FROM statement.

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    UNNEST([1,2,3]) as num
)

select * from x
```